# curl hangs in docker, but not on host machine

Tags: docker, ubuntu, networking, tcp, google-bigquery

We're currently having an issue where `curl bigquery.googleapis.com` sometimes hangs indefinitely inside a `ubuntu:20.04` local docker container, but always works (returns a 404) on the host macOS machine and in production. The container is running a Python Flask application.

Some observations:

- It's flakey, `curl bigquery.googleapis.com` works when the container initializes, but trying again ~10 mins later hangs. Eventually, the command will work again and `curl -v` shows it's trying to connect to a different IP.
- We don't have this issue on production, or on any host machine.
- Different people on our team experience the issue at different times, on different IPs.
- During the issue, connections to other google services (e.g. `curl servicemanagement.googleapis.com`) works fine.
- During the issue, the command works in another docker container with a different image.
- Issue has occurred across many macOS Docker versions.
- Curling directly to the IPv4 address also hangs.

Interestingly, doing `netstat` on the host machine shows all connections as `ESTABLISHED`, but doing `netstat` inside the container shows them as `SYN_SENT`.

We hypothesize that the connection is being kept alive on the host, but is killed in the container. Or, certain ACKs aren't being forwarded correctly to the container for some reason.

**`netstat` on macOS**
[image: netstat inside container]

**`netstat` inside container**
[image: netstat on host]

**TCP Dump**
[image: TCP Dump]

**curl -v output**

```
root@cf8bd850e9ab:/code# curl -v bigquery.googleapis.com
*   Trying 142.251.35.170:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:4006:81e::200a:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2607:f8b0:4006:81e::200a: Cannot assign requested address
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:4006:81e::200a:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2607:f8b0:4006:81e::200a: Cannot assign requested address
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:4006:81e::200a:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2607:f8b0:4006:81e::200a: Cannot assign requested address
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:4006:81e::200a:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2607:f8b0:4006:81e::200a: Cannot assign requested address
```

Additional output:

- `netstat -p`: https://pastebin.com/sKQ23yah
- `curl --ipv4`: https://pastebin.com/3N7Q6aB4

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.docker.com/t/curl-hangs-in-docker-but-not-on-host-machine/125388

Comment: run netstat with the `-p` option so we can confirm that it is curl holding the TCP session. You're getting `EADDRNOTAVAIL ` on the IPv6 address, try forcing curl to be ipv4 only, `--ipv4` and see what happens.

Comment: Looks like you are on a network with IPv6. Is it? Does the host has IPv4?
The reason for hang is - DNS resolution with the nameserver takes time.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! curl fails on both IPv4 and IPv6. Curling directly to the IP address also hangs. Here's the results of those commands:
netstat -p: https://pastebin.com/sKQ23yah
curl -v --ipv4 bigquery.googleapis.com: https://pastebin.com/3N7Q6aB4

Comment: @RajaRavindra Also to clarify, by hanging I mean the curl command never completes and eventually will time out
@LiamKelly The `9/python3` on the `netstat -p` output is the flask application that connects/performs queries on BigQuery

Comment: I can comment more, if you can post the time out error and its trace. But as I understand; the reason it times out is because it never resolves the host as I said earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the DNS while running the container with `--dns` flag or you can configure it by adding an entry in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` which could probably help with the resolution.